# Streaming device data from IoThub in one organization(Org/Client A) to IoThub in entirely different organization(Org/Client B)

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to clone my device data and stream the device data to another IoThub in an entirely different organization, the organization here I mean a different vendor cloud.

**Trial:**
I have tried routing the messages to service bus topics from my IoThub and then written a container using the service bus SDK which can subscribe to these topics and push the data to Azure IoT hub in a different vendor cloud.

**ASK:** 
Is there any other best way for sending the device stream to another vendor Azure IoThub other than the above using Azure alone.

I can directly stream the device data from the data source, which is clearly not the use case.

Using IoT-device, not IoT-Edge.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what you really want to achieve. If I understand correctly, you want to forward data from IoT Hub A into an IoT Hub B. And by forward you mean, to ingest it into B like it was coming from a device directly into B?!

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear above, yes I want to stream data to IoThub B  as the data is directly(delay is acceptable) coming to B. Whereas the actual data is the stream to IoThub A and IoThub B is subscribing to IoThub A.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible out of the box. You need a processor in the middle that picks up messages from IoT Hub A - for instance on its built-in Event Hub endpoint. Then the processor would need to **impersonate** each device for which it got a message from A, and send the message to IoT Hub B, using the device credentials for the respective device.

You could for example build this with an Azure Function. But you need to build all this yourself.

Comment: please accept the answer (and possibly upvote if you like), if this solved your problem